# Help to understand: "the headline writer for Cleveland Cavaliers beat writer Chris Fedor’s story in The Plain Dealer did his job Thursday"

Tags: sentence-structure

> The purpose of a headline, they say in journalism school, is to draw the reader in, **so the headline writer for Cleveland Cavaliers beat writer Chris Fedor’s story in The Plain Dealer did his job Thursday**.

The sentence in Bold is very confusing to me. It seem to me that **beat** is the verb of the main clause, but what about "**did his job**"? Also, how come **a writer**(for Cleveland Cavaliers) can beat **a story**(writer Chris Fedor’s story)? It doesn't look logical.

So, I am wondering how to parse the sentence correctly? Maybe, it makes more sense to insert a "**who**":

> the headline writer for Cleveland Cavaliers **[** **who** beat writer Chris Fedor’s story in The Plain Dealer **]** did his job Thursday.

The [full source](https://sports.yahoo.com/cleveland-newspaper-headline-takes-passive-aggressive-shot-lebron-james-165657915.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this is a very convoluted sentence and it's not surprising that you are confused.

Second, **beat** as used in the sentence isn't the verb *to beat*. It's a type of newspaper writer.

The wikiHow article ["How to Be a Beat Writer"](https://www.wikihow.com/Be-a-Beat-Writer) describes this term:

> Experienced reporters are usually assigned a beat, an area they cover on a regular basis, when hired by a media entity. Depending on staffing, you may be assigned a beat on a subject area unfamiliar to you. Whether working for a newspaper, radio or TV station, or a news website, you need to understand how to develop your skills to become the best beat writer in your field.

---

So, let's analyze the sentence.

- There was a headline writer.
- He wrote a headline for a story published in *The Plain Dealer*.
- The author of the story was Chris Fedor.
- Chris Fedor was a beat writer who wrote stories about the Cleveland Caveliers (they are a basketball team) as part of his beat.
- The headline writer did his job on Thursday when he wrote the headline for the story.
- We can infer (from the part of the sentence not in bold) that the headline was successful in its attempt to draw in readers.

Answer (score 1):

I found this sentence really confusing, too, until I finally figured out that "beat writer" is a noun phrase here.

The correct interpretation is "the headline writer for [the story] in The Plain Dealer did his job Thursday", where *the story* is "Cleveland Cavaliers beat writer Chris Fedor's story". This last phrase means "the story written by Chris Fedor, who is a beat writer for the Cleveland Cavaliers".

It's a badly written sentence. A better way to write it would have been something like this:

> The purpose of a headline, they say in journalism school, is to draw the reader in. A headline writer for The Plain Dealer did his job Thursday when he wrote the headline for a story by Cleveland Cavaliers beat writer Chris Fedor.