# Is the expression "Police Scotland" grammaticaly correct?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I just ran across this expression **Police Scotland**, that normally it could be Scotland Police or Police of Scotland, but since it was pronounced formally on their website, it got a question for me:

- [link to “Welcome to Police Scotland"](http://www.scotland.police.uk)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Police Scotland is the 'marketing name' for the Police Service of Scotland. Marketing names do not have to be 'grammatical', preceded by articles, or even correctly spelled - for 
 example, Pizza Hut (not "The Pizza Hut"), Kwik Fit (not "Quick Fit"), etc. Another UK agency is called "Border Force", and that is its official name.

[Border Force Director-General](https://www.civilserviceworld.com/articles/news/home-office-names-new-border-force-director-general)

> The Police Service of Scotland - which will be known as Police
>   Scotland - will begin its beat in two weeks.
>
> On 1 April, the new 17,000-strong single national force will replace
>   the current eight-force structure and become the second largest force
>   in the UK, after the Metropolitan Police in London.

[BBC News](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-scotland-21820882)

Comment: FabioS - Some things on meta that might be worth reading: [_When should I accept an answer?_](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer) and [_Are thanks for answers unnecessary?_](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4744/are-thanks-for-the-answers-unnecessary)

Comment: It’s worth noting that _police_ can be used as a verb, so the expression _police Scotland_ is a grammatical way to describe the mission of the force – even if it is an unusual name for the force itself.

Comment: A similar example is "Team  GB"

Comment: What does "begin its beat" mean by the way? I couldn't find anywhere it's been defined.

Comment: @dan According to Cambridge Dictionary: beat [noun] an area for which someone, such as a police officer, has responsibility as part of their job. I think that they will begin working in its beat or that its beat will become active in two weeks but maybe you should ask a new question to get native English speakers' insight.

Comment: @dan I answered another question of yours about *beat* a little while ago. (https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/175720/help-to-understand-the-headline-writer-for-cleveland-cavaliers-beat-writer-chr/175725#175725) It was with respect to reporters having a beat, but the same is true of police.

Comment: A copper will tell you that toms have beats too.

Comment: @JasonBassford I noticed that, but the phrasing "begin its beat" is a bit confusing.

Comment: Dan, it was the BBC headline writer being witty. The new police organisation is being compared to a police officer starting a patrol or 'beat'. If it had been connected with the navy, the headline might have said "The Naval Boat Service of Scotland will set sail in two weeks", or if it was related to aviation, "will take to the skies in two weeks".